# Finding the maximum of two functions with complicated formulas

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let
$$
f(\omega)=1+\frac{m(a+\omega^2)}{a^2+\omega^2}+\alpha\left(\frac{a^2+\omega^2-ma}{a^2+\omega^2}\right)\cos(\omega\tau)+\frac{\alpha m\omega}{a^2+\omega^2}\sin(\omega\tau)\;,
$$
and
$$
g(\omega)=\frac{m\omega(a-1)}{a^2+\omega^2}+\frac{\alpha}{a^2+\omega^2}[ma+\tau (a^2+\omega^2)]\sin(\omega\tau)+\frac{m\omega\alpha}{a^2+\omega^2}\cos(\omega\tau)\;,
$$
where
$\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\omega,m,a,\tau\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$. I need some help determining $\mbox{max}\{f(\omega),g(\omega)\}$. In thinking about this problem, I'm interested in very general conditions on the parameters. I know the value of looking at special cases, but there are technically infinitely many special cases here. I don't see the value of looking at the special case $m=a=\tau=1$, for instance, when there are countless other such special cases one could possibly look at. I read somewhere that the maximum of two functions, h(w) and g(w), is $\frac{1}{2}[(h+g)+(h-g)]$, but I don't have a clue how this type of `result' may be used here.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the answer for particular cases like $m=a=\tau=1$? What if one of $m,a,\tau$ is far far larger than the other two?

Comment: The formula for max should be : $\frac{1}{2}[(h+g)+|(h-g)|]$